# Question about Node.js event loop vs Browser's event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I understand that the Node.js event loop performs non-blocking I/O operations in a single-threaded environment. What I need to clear about is that I have also learned there is another event loop built into the browser, for example, chrome’s v8 engine has its own event loop. Since Node.js executes javascript code using chrome’s v8 engine, does that mean it is the same event loop that browsers execute their Javascript code with? If Node.js has its own implementation of the event loop, then how is it implemented to work with `libuv` library?

Comment: The event loop is not part of the javascript engine, it actually orchestrates the different parts of the program and defers to the javascript engine for execution. Both the browser and node offer a complete execution environment for javascript, and the javascript engine and the event loop are only two components of a larger whole. I think libuv is the library that Node.js uses to implement its event loop.